# Post on behalf of a Facebook Workplace user

Tags: facebook-workplace

I would like our Facebook Workplace users to share articles from an internal application, into Facebook Workplace. I have been able to do this by creating posts with the BOT username of my app, but I would like the comments to come through as if I were logged in as the individual users. I have tried the FB js SDK but I get an error:

> "Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
> domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains
> of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

I cannot find where I can add this URL in.

Is it possible to create posts on behalf of Facebook Workplace users?

I noticed this:

[image]

but it doesn't offer up an alternative solution. src: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/integrations/custom-integrations/reference/member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered by a Facebook Workplace developer so this holds weight.

- You cannot impersonate users anymore. There are a tiny select companies who were too embedded into that functionality to remove it from them, but for all intents and purposes, treat it as a no go zone from now on and in no way will a super large customer be able to sway their opinion on that decision.
- They have introduced Facebook plugins that will allow reaction interactions but it has limited purpose. Worth checking out as it may cover your requirements

As a solution:

- Add a button that takes you through to Facebook Workplace using the permalinks provided in the comment edge responses.